# pyinstaller .exe not starting properly

Tags: python, pyinstaller

Hello Im learning python for my studies.
Right now im trying to use pyinstaller to get an .exe file since its easier to share.

My small program use tkinter, numpy and matplotlib but when i try to start it, nothing happens, its quite weird because I get no error in the compiling process :

```
    pyinstaller main.spec
531 INFO: PyInstaller: 3.4.dev0+133d18156
531 INFO: Python: 3.6.2
531 INFO: Platform: Windows-10-10.0.15063-SP0
531 INFO: UPX is not available.
531 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['C:\\Users\\Charles\\eclipse-workspace\\algo2\\src',
 'C:\\Users\\Charles\\eclipse-workspace\\algo2\\src']
531 INFO: checking Analysis
531 INFO: Building Analysis because out00-Analysis.toc is non existent
531 INFO: Initializing module dependency graph...
546 INFO: Initializing module graph hooks...
578 INFO: Analyzing base_library.zip ...
4672 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'os'
4719 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'stat'
4719 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'ntpath'
4781 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'genericpath'
4797 INFO: running Analysis out00-Analysis.toc
4812 INFO: Adding Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls to dependent assemblies of final executable
  required by c:\users\charles\anaconda3\python.exe
5906 INFO: Caching module hooks...
5922 INFO: Analyzing main.py
5937 INFO: Loading module hooks...
5937 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-encodings.py"...
6078 INFO: Looking for ctypes DLLs
6078 INFO: Analyzing run-time hooks ...
6078 INFO: Looking for dynamic libraries
6078 INFO: Looking for eggs
6078 INFO: Using Python library c:\users\charles\anaconda3\python36.dll
6078 INFO: Found binding redirects:
[]
6109 INFO: Graph cross-reference written to C:\Users\Charles\eclipse-workspace\algo2\src\build\main\xref-main.html
6141 INFO: checking PYZ
6141 INFO: Building PYZ because out00-PYZ.toc is non existent
6141 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) C:\Users\Charles\eclipse-workspace\algo2\src\build\main\out00-PYZ.pyz
6344 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) C:\Users\Charles\eclipse-workspace\algo2\src\build\main\out00-PYZ.pyz completed successfully.
6344 INFO: checking PKG
6344 INFO: Building PKG because out00-PKG.toc is non existent
6344 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) out00-PKG.pkg
6406 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) out00-PKG.pkg completed successfully.
6422 INFO: Bootloader c:\users\charles\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\bootloader\Windows-64bit\run_d.exe
6422 INFO: checking EXE
6422 INFO: Building EXE because out00-EXE.toc is non existent
6422 INFO: Building EXE from out00-EXE.toc
6422 INFO: Appending archive to EXE C:\Users\Charles\eclipse-workspace\algo2\src\build\main\main.exe
6516 INFO: Building EXE from out00-EXE.toc completed successfully.
6531 INFO: checking COLLECT
6531 INFO: Building COLLECT because out00-COLLECT.toc is non existent
6547 INFO: Building COLLECT out00-COLLECT.toc
7359 INFO: Building COLLECT out00-COLLECT.toc completed successfully.
```

So i tried to compile with debug, i do not see something wrong :

```
main.exe>log.txt
[3912] PyInstaller Bootloader 3.x
[3912] LOADER: executable is C:\Users\Charles\eclipse-workspace\algo2\src\dist\main\main.exe
[3912] LOADER: homepath is C:\Users\Charles\eclipse-workspace\algo2\src\dist\main
[3912] LOADER: _MEIPASS2 is NULL
[3912] LOADER: archivename is C:\Users\Charles\eclipse-workspace\algo2\src\dist\main\main.exe
[3912] LOADER: No need to extract files to run; setting extractionpath to homepath
[3912] LOADER: SetDllDirectory(C:\Users\Charles\eclipse-workspace\algo2\src\dist\main)
[3912] LOADER: Already in the child - running user's code.
[3912] LOADER: Python library: C:\Users\Charles\eclipse-workspace\algo2\src\dist\main\python36.dll
[3912] LOADER: Loaded functions from Python library.
[3912] LOADER: Manipulating environment (sys.path, sys.prefix)
[3912] LOADER: Pre-init sys.path is C:\Users\Charles\eclipse-workspace\algo2\src\dist\main\base_library.zip;C:\Users\Charles\eclipse-workspace\algo2\src\dist\main
[3912] LOADER: sys.prefix is C:\Users\Charles\eclipse-workspace\algo2\src\dist\main
[3912] LOADER: Setting runtime options
[3912] LOADER: Initializing python
[3912] LOADER: Overriding Python's sys.path
[3912] LOADER: Post-init sys.path is C:\Users\Charles\eclipse-workspace\algo2\src\dist\main\base_library.zip;C:\Users\Charles\eclipse-workspace\algo2\src\dist\main
[3912] LOADER: Setting sys.argv
[3912] LOADER: setting sys._MEIPASS
[3912] LOADER: importing modules from CArchive
[3912] LOADER: extracted struct
[3912] LOADER: callfunction returned...
[3912] LOADER: extracted pyimod01_os_path
[3912] LOADER: callfunction returned...
[3912] LOADER: extracted pyimod02_archive
[3912] LOADER: callfunction returned...
[3912] LOADER: extracted pyimod03_importers
[3912] LOADER: callfunction returned...
[3912] LOADER: Installing PYZ archive with Python modules.
[3912] LOADER: PYZ archive: out00-PYZ.pyz
[3912] LOADER: Running pyiboot01_bootstrap.py
[3912] LOADER: OK.
[3912] LOADER: Cleaning up Python interpreter.
```

Here my .spec file :

```
# -*- mode: python -*-
import sys

block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['main.py'],
             pathex=['C:\\Users\\Charles\\eclipse-workspace\\algo2\\src'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[],
             hiddenimports=['os', 'stat', 'ntpath', 'genericpath'],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher
             )
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher
             )
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.binaries + [('msvcp100.dll', 'C:\\Windows\\System32\\msvcp100.dll', 'BINARY'),
                        ('msvcr100.dll', 'C:\\Windows\\System32\\msvcr100.dll', 'BINARY')]
          if sys.platform == 'win32' else a.binaries,
          exclude_binaries=True,
          name='main',
          debug=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=False,
          console=False )
coll = COLLECT(exe,
               a.binaries,
               a.zipfiles,
               a.datas,
               strip=False,
               upx=False,
               name='main')
```

My program works without problem if i run it with the python interpreter.
Tried to start the .exe with and without console, nothing happens.

Any idea ?

Thanks

Thanks

Comment: To reference files in code you need to use `sys._MEIPASS` as the base path when using pyinstaller - this is a common source of bugs.

Comment: I tried using your method, i do not have files to add between, everything needed is in my main.py .
Now im getting :
site-package\PyInstaller\loader\pyiboot01_bootstrap.py line 25, ModuleNotFindError : no module named 'os'

Comment: Did you import os?

Comment: No, my program doesnt use os, thats why i tryed to add it to the spec file.
its the pyiboot01_boostrap.py file from pyinstaller who tries to import it but fails : File "site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyiboot01_bootstrap.py", line 25, in <module> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'os'

Comment: Did that module import os?

Comment: Yes it does, its a part of pyinstaller code.

Comment: I answered a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46499068/pyinstaller-not-loading-dll/46679099#46679099. It could be of use to you.

Comment: Fixed using python 3.4 instead of 3.6

Answer (score 0):

How did you tell pyinstaller to compile the `.py` file?

If you installed pyinstaller with pip, try running this is the command prompt on the same directory as the file.

`pyinstaller mypythonapp.py`

The `.exe` will be in a new directory called `dist`. To get the exe as one file use the `--onefile` parameter in the command prompt when compiling.

Comment: I tried with and without --onefile.
I keep getting an error message if i compile directly with these commands :
site-package\PyInstaller\loader\pyiboot01_bootstrap.py line 25,
ModuleNotFindError : no module named 'os'

Comment: Are you trying to use os without importing it?

Comment: Nop im not using os in my code, its the pyiboot01_boostrap.py file from pyinstaller who tries to import it but fails :
File "site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyiboot01_bootstrap.py", line 25, in <module> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'os'

Comment: Have you tried compiling a basic application that just prints `Hello, World!` to check if pyinstaller works on your computer?